# Ocultar Elementos en HTML y Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy haciendo un cuestionario en HTML y Jquery, al hacer click en una imagen que contiene una pregunta que se encuentra dentro de un section quiero que ese section se oculte y aparezca el section siguiente, con Jquery hago una seleccion de las clases que contienen los section y me muestre el id de cada uno de los section para saber en que section estoy actualmente, poder ocultarlo y mostrar el siguiente pero no encuentro la manera de que no me siga tomando el primer section que encuentra en el HTML ya que siempre me muestra el id 1 que es el primero.

¿Hay alguna manera de destruir completamente después de haber ocupado un section?

```
  <main class="main">

        <section class="seccion" id="1">
            <h2>Pregunta 1</h2>

            <div class="cuestionario">

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="1-1">
                        <img src="img/icono1.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="1-2">
                        <img src="img/icono2.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="1-3">
                        <img src="img/icono3.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="seccion" id="2" style="display: none">
            <h2>Pregunta 2</h2>

            <div class="cuestionario">

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="2-1">
                        <img src="img/icono1.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 4</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="2-2">
                        <img src="img/icono2.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 5</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="2-3">
                        <img src="img/icono3.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 6</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


        <section class="seccion" id="3" style="display: block">
            <h2>Pregunta 3</h2>

            <div class="cuestionario">

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="3-1">
                        <img src="img/icono1.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 4</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="3-2">
                        <img src="img/icono2.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 5</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="columnas">
                    <div class="contenido" id="3-3">
                        <img src="img/icono3.png" alt="">
                        <p>item 6</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
       </main>
```

-------------------------- Jquery -------------------------

```
  $(document).ready(function () {



  $('.contenido').click(function () {


    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    var seccion = $('.seccion').attr("id");
    console.log(seccion);

    if (seccion == 1) {
        seccion1();
        $('#1').css('display', 'none');
        $('#2').css('display', 'block');
    }

     function seccion1() {


        switch (id) {

            case '1-1':

                console.log('Precio = 5000');
                break;

            case '1-2':

                console.log('Precio = 2500');
                break;

            case '1-3':
                console.log('Precio = 8000');
                break;
         }

     }

  });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función .remove() para eliminar el elemento que quieras del DOM. O puedes crear una función que utilice a su vez la función .toggle() para mostrar u ocultar el elemento.

Answer (score 4):

Podrias tomar por `Jquery` en vez de la clase, el `id` y esconderlo sin cambiar las propiedades de css, solo hacerlo con el `show | hide` de `jquery` de esta manera:

```
Function(){
$('#1').hide();
$('#2').show();}
```

**PD: Esto no es para eliminar del DOM el elemento, solo para esconderlo y hacerlo aparecer, tambien puedes usar `toggle();` dependiendo de lo que busques hacer.**

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar la propiedad next:
para el elemento siguiente

```
 $(".seccion").next().css("display","none");
```

para el elemento actual seria:

```
$(this).hide();
```